# Не могу присвоить класс объекту при клике и при пролистывании.

Tags: javascript

Вообщем прописал в css для активного li класса свойства, в хедере прописал код который при клике на объект должен задавать кликнотому li класс active. что только не пробывал-не получается. думаю может проблема в сss. голова уже не варит совсем. хелп!!
ссылка на сайт [1](http://www.masterskaya-zarizin.ru/)

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#undefined-sticky-wrapper li a').click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});

Comment: проблему выделите, код выложите, сюда самые важные части, на jsfiddle, чтобы можно было повторить проблему. ссылка на ваш сайт не полезна сообществу, т.к. рано или поздно оно починится и проблемы не будет.

Comment: ахах, выложить целый сайт? js библиотеки тоже прикладывать?

Comment: **проблему выделите**

Comment: проблема в том что верёвка с мылом уже кажутся естественным способом выхода. ))) Проблема лишь в том, что я никак не могу "зацепить" меню никаким js кодом... (( при клике на меню class active не присваивается и остаётся на месте

Comment: вот так это обычно делается http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rY7VZ/, чем ваш пример отличается не сильно понятно.

Comment: тем что на него можно взглянуть, а по вашей ссылке лишь error/
щас соберу, если вы настаиваете

Comment: не пойму, если собираю всё на jsfiddle то всё работает, если на сайте-нет.

Comment: там запятая лишняя,  http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/rY7VZ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае:

```
jQuery('#undefined-sticky-wrapper li a').click(function() {
    jQuery('.active').removeClass('active'); 
    jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active'); 
});
```

или так:

```
jQuery('#undefined-sticky-wrapper').on('click', 'li', function() {
    jQuery(this.parentNode.children).removeClass('active')
      .filter(this).addClass('active'); 
});
```

Переключение класса при прокрутке страницы (добавьте класс 'bg' на слайд с контактами только):

```
var $bg = jQuery('.bg').filter(function() {
    return this.className.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').split(' ').length === 1
}),
    $links = jQuery('#undefined-sticky-wrapper li');

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
   var indexPage = 0;

   jQuery.each($bg, function(index) {
       if (this.offsetTop <= jQuery(window).scrollTop()) {
           indexPage = index + 1;
       }
   });

   if (!$links.eq(indexPage).hasClass('active')) {
       $links.removeClass('active').eq(indexPage).addClass('active');
   }
});
```

Comment: Вы меня побьёте но не работает ни первый ни второй )))

Comment: Скопируйте последний код, откройте свой сайт, откройте консоль браузера (F12 в хроме), вставьте код и запустите. Все должно работать)

Comment: У вас работало? может я что-то не понял? все делаю как вы говорили, но результата 0. ушёл отсыпаться короч. утро вечера мудренее ))) за помощь большущее Вам спасибо!!!

Comment: Возможно вы используете старый браузер. Поменял запись window.pageYOffset на jQuery(window).scrollTop(). Код проверял в Хроме и ИЕ8, все ок.

Comment: использую хром, обновлённый. можете сохранить страницу и сбросить её мне, был бы очень признателен! volgogradforever@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Вы класс active применяете элементу a. Измените код так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ $('#undefined-sticky-wrapper li a').click(function() { $('.active').removeClass('active'); $(this).parent('li').addClass('active'); }); });
```

Comment: Делал я и так, прописал как вы написали. не помогло к сожалению. =(